# Удаление строки/столбца массива

Tags: php

Задача удалить столбец или строку в двумерном массиве полностью, что бы на ее место сьехала следующая и длина сократилась на 1. Я пробовал `array_splice();` без указания `replacement` но длина массива не сокращается, при чем при применении `sort();` данные уходят не в начало(вверх если строка), а в конец - вниз, после чего при выводе первая строка это пустая линия.

Есть какой-то рабочий способ правильно урезать массив?

Сейчас я делаю так(ввод массива - unset - вывод):

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
        $hh[$i][$j]="$i$j";
        echo $hh[$i][$j]." ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}

//array_splice($hh[1],0,10);
unset($hh[5]);

for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
        echo $hh[$i][$j]." ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Вывод:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 

60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

В итоге проблема та же, пустая строка на том же индексе. Изначально был `array_splice($hh[5],0,10);`.

Comment: Приведите пример массива, то как вы пытаетесь удалить строку/столбец, ожидаемый результат и то что получаете

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev обновил.

Comment: Кажись я понял. Я вывожу перенос строки лишний раз. Но я думал PHP будет ругать если наступить на несуществующий индекс. Тоесть индекс 10-го элемента все так же существует либо я ничего не понимаю в массивах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот 2 функции для чистого удаления строки или столбца в двумерном массиве с числовыми индексами

```
function array_row_remove($array, $row_index)
{
    if (is_array($array) && array_key_exists($row_index, $array))
    {
        unset($array[$row_index]);
        $array = array_values($array);
    }

    return $array;
}

function array_col_remove($array, $col_index)
{
    if (is_array($array) && count($array))
    {
        foreach ($array as $row_index => $row)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($col_index, $row))
            {
                unset($array[$row_index][$col_index]);
                $array[$row_index] = array_values($array[$row_index]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Идеально, благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

С кодом, который удаляет строку проблем нет, а вот с кодом вывода есть.

Проблема в том, что после выполнения

```
unset($hh[5]);
```

в массиве больше не остается строки с индексом `5`. Тем не менее, при выводе вы все равно к ней обращаетесь. Если бы вы настроили логирование PHP на вывод замечаний, то получили бы что-то вроде:

> PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in ...

Решение проблемы тривиально: вам нужно переиндексировать массив. А сделать это можно, например, так:

```
unset($hh[5]);
$hh = array_values($hh);
```

Ну и вместо жестко зашитого количества строк/столбцов, правильнее было бы использовать функцию [`count`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.count.php):

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($hh); $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j < count($hh[$i]); $j++) {
        echo $hh[$i][$j]." ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь все понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, что Вам нужна функция unset. Она удалит строку из массива по переданному ключу. 
Пример использования:

```
unset($arrayExample[0]);
```

В результате из Вашего массива будет удалено значение, соответствующее ключу 0 вместе с самим ключом.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, в него добавил вывод который и есть проблемой. Как избежать пустой строки? И 2) как удалить столбец таким способом?

Comment: Дмитрий дал верный ответ ниже, не буду дублировать. Думаю, что это и есть решение Вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ уже описан другими людьми, но я нашел еще один вариант, правда я не до конца понимаю почему он сработал, но тем не менее.

Можно конечно вывести и переиндексированный массив, а можно пройтись по всем элементам что остались:

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
        $hh[$i][$j]="$i$j"; echo $hh[$i][$j]." ";
    } 
    echo "<br>";
}
echo "<hr>";
unset($hh[5]);
//$hh = array_values($hh);
foreach ($hh as $i => $value) {
    foreach ($hh[$i] as $j => $value1) {
        echo($hh[$i][$j])." ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Используя `foreach` вы перебираете только существующие ключи. Используя `for` вы выбираете, по мимо прочих, уже не существующие ключи.